# Programmatic backup on appengine for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backup, google-cloud-storage

I wanted to run backup jobs programmatically on GAE for Java.
So I have tried to port the code described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792027/run-appengine-backup-from-task-queue) to work on Appengine for Java:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();

String backendAddress = BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("ah-builtin-python-bundle");
    TaskOptions taskOptions = withUrl("/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create")
            .method(TaskOptions.Method.GET)
            .param("name", "Backup_Task")
            .param("filesystem", "gs")
            .param("gs_bucket_name", "backup_bkt")
            .param("queue", queue.getQueueName())
            .header("Host", backendAddress).
            .param("kind", "customer")
            .param("kind", "address")
 queue.add(taskOptions);
```

All that seems correct. When I run the above code it adds the task call to push quueue, however doesn't execute it on ah-builtin-python-bundle, but on the default version of my app, which obviously returns 404. See logs below:

> 2013-10-02 15:58:27.315 /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=Backup_Task&filesystem=gs&gs_bucket_name=backup&queue=next-version&kind=address&kind=customer 404 26ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
>   0.1.0.2 - - [02/Oct/2013:08:58:27 -0700] "GET /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=Backup_Task&filesystem=gs&gs_bucket_name=backup&queue=next-version&kind=address&kind=customer HTTP/1.1" 404 294 "http://version.myapp.appspot.com/tasks/backup" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "version.myapp.appspot.com" ms=26 cpu_ms=47 cpm_usd=0.000033 queue_name=next-version task_name=3563633336363 app_engine_release=1.8.5 instance=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I have also seen code [here](https://github.com/StreakYC/mache/blob/80c89dc0eaf0162906339a62430f196d21f36cac/src/com/streak/datastore/analysis/builtin/BuiltinDatastoreToBigqueryCronTask.java#L36) which is doing the same, but I am not sure if it works correctly.

I wonder, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi, same issue here.  Did you work it out please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found was the following:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("backupQueue");
TaskOptions taskOptions = withUrl("/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create")
            .method(TaskOptions.Method.GET)
            .param("name", 'Backuptask')
            .param("filesystem", "gs")
            .param("gs_bucket_name", BACKUP_BUCKET + '/' + DateTime.now().toString("yyyy/MM/dd/'" + nameSpace + "'-HH-mm"))
            .param("namespace", NamespaceManager.get();)
            .param("queue", queue.getQueueName())
            .param("kind", "customer")
            .param("kind", "address");
queue.add(taskOptions);
```

The trick was to use `backupQueue` which would target `ah-builtin-python-bundle`. You can do this by adding the following to `queue.xml`:`

`<queue>
        <!-- a queue for backups tasks -->
        <name>backupQueue</name>
        <rate>1/s</rate>
        <bucket-size>10</bucket-size>
        <max-concurrent-requests>3</max-concurrent-requests>
        <retry-parameters>
            <!-- only 1 retry attempt -->
            <task-retry-limit>2</task-retry-limit>
        </retry-parameters>
        <target>ah-builtin-python-bundle</target>
</queue>`

Comment: Man this is incredible! we've been struggling with this issue until finding this gem by accident.

You can even go over the kinds in each namespace and add them to get a generic namespace backup/restore thing going.

Comment: We are using something similar and this works well.  Now the next trick is how to get a list of pending/running backups so that you don't overlap.  Did you figure that out?

Comment: the only way is to check taskqueue and that will only tell you if backup finished or not. The main problem with this method, is you can't run managed backup per namespace.

Comment: i came up with near-exact same Java code by myself playing with the API. The difference being that I was using the defaultQueue with the end result being that the backup wasnt happening. I'll try with a different queue as above.