# Automatically retain latest datastore backup

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I'm looking for the best strategy to collect specific datastore *.backup_info files stored in Cloud Storage and copy them as the "latest" backup_info files per kind, so I have a fix location for each kind, where the most recent backup_info file is found, e.g.

```
gs://MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/latest/Comment.backup_info
```

Basically, I have a Google App Engine app (Python standard) with data in Cloud Datastore. I can run a cron-job to perform backups automatically and regularly as described in the docs [Scheduled Backups](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups) and I can also write a bit of Python code to execute backup tasks which is triggered manually as [described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31710602/1549523). I plan to write a small Python cron-job that would perform the task to find the most recent backup_info file of a given kind and copy/rename it to the desired location.

Either way, the original backup location will be crowded with lots of files and folders during a day, especially if there is more than one backup for a certain kind. For example in `gs://MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/` I will find:

```
VeryLoooooongRandomLookingString.backup_info
OtherStringForSecondBackup.backup_info
OtherStringForThirdBackup.backup_info
```

The string seems to be a unique identifier for every backup execution. I assume, it contains a list of *.backup_info files, one for each kind in the backup.

```
VeryLoooooongRandomLookingString.Comment.backup_info
OtherStringForSecondBackup.Comment.backup_info
OtherStringForThirdBackup.Comment.backup_info
```

For every kind in the backup, e.g. "Comment". It seems it contains a list of actual backup data for this kind and this backup.

```
datastore_backup_CUSTOM_PREFIX_2017_09_20_Comment/
datastore_backup_CUSTOM_PREFIX_2017_09_20_1_Comment/
datastore_backup_CUSTOM_PREFIX_2017_09_20_2_Comment/
```

Data folder for each backup and kind. Here for kind "Comment", backed up three times on 9/20.

My questions are related to **Datastore** and/or **Storage**:

1. Is it possible to explicitly specify a custom UID as a query parameter (or in HTTP header) when calling `/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create`?
2. If not, is it possible to send a message with the UID to a hook or something, after the backup has been completed?
3. If (1) and (2) is not possible: Which approach would be the best in **Storage** to find the latest *.backup_info file for a given kind? It seems that listbucket() doesn't allow filtering, and I don't think that iterating through hundreds or thousands of files looking for certain name patterns would be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two solutions for the problem, one is in GA and one is in Beta.

The answers in short:

1. The GA [Datastore Export & Import service](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) allows custom and predictable paths to the backup
2. and its API for [long-running operations](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#managing_long-running_operations) allows to get the output URL of a backup job (e.g. for paths with timestamps).
3. A Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Storage events would allow to handle just specific `[KIND].backup_info` files as soon as they are added to a bucket, instead of paging through thousands of files in the bucket each time.

## Datastore Export & Import

This new service has an API to run export jobs ([manually](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_entities) or [scheduled](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export)). The job allows to specify the path and produces predictable full paths, so existing backup files could be overwritten if only the latest backup is needed at any time, e.g.:

```
gs://[YOUR_BUCKET]/[PATH]/[NAMESPACE]/[KIND]/[NAMESPACE]_[KIND].export_metadata
```

For cron-jobs, the App Engine handler URL is `/cloud-datastore-export` (instead of the old `/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create`). Also the format of the export is different from the old export. It can be imported to BigQuery, too, just like the old `[KIND].backup_info` files.

## Cloud Function

Deploy a Cloud Function (JavaScript / Node.js) that is triggered by any change in the backup bucket and if that file exists (`file.resourceState === 'not_exists'`), is new (`file.metageneration === '1'`) and in fact is one of the `[KIND].backup_info` files we want, it will be copied to a different bucket ("latest_backups" or so). Custom metadata on the copy can be used to compare `timeCreated` in later executions of the function (so we don't accidentally overwrite more recent backup file with older file). Copying or moving actual backup payload will break the references inside the `[KINDNAME].backup_info` files though.

- [Background Cloud Function with a Cloud Storage trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage)
- [How to copy files in Cloud Functions (Node.JS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-moving-objects#storage-copy-object-nodejs)